# Name of matrix whose columns are basis of kenel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I recently was puzzled by the fact that I was lacking terminology when speaking about the following: given a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, is there a name for the matrices $K$ whose columns span $\mathrm{ker}(A)$? We speak about the $\mathrm{null}(A)$ or $\mathrm{ker}(A)$ as the null space or the kernel of the matrix.

In practice we have:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{ker}(A) @>K>> \mathbb{R}^n @>A>> \mathbb{R}^m\\
\end{CD}

Does $K$ have a specific name? Nullity of $A$?

Comment: I had a similar problem in a technical note I was writing. I ended up referring to it as the nullity of $A$, but I made sure to clearly define what I meant up front. It by no means is standard terminology.

Comment: This matrix cannot be given a name because it is far from being unique... You cannot say "the" matrix whose columns...

Comment: @Jean Marie - Fair point of not being unique, should write "a" there. I edited the question.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your diagram. $K$ is providing a map from what to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, exactly? Also, I can't think of a common enough use for this matrix that it would merit having a special name. I would probably just call it a basis matrix for the null space.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers - Say that I have $AB=0$ assume that $A$  has no full rank. Then I can write $B = K W$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But it does not help me understand the diagram ($\mathrm{ker}(A)$ is already a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and the domain of the map given by $K$ should be $\mathbb{R}^{\dim{(\mathrm{ker{(A)}}}}$), or convince me that this matrix is likely to have a special name.

Comment: I guess you mean $K:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^n$ of maximal rank and with image equal to $\operatorname{ker}(A)$, right?

Comment: As Morgan Rodgers says, actually

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers - yes, you are correct that one should put $\mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}\mathrm{ker}(A)}$, but it is generally accepted to denote this subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as just $\mathrm{ker}(A)$ in the diagram, as far as I can tell. After all these very good comments I definitely agree that $K$ does not 'deserve' a special name given it is not so very special after all. Thanks!

Comment: The diagram (exact sequence) I have seen is $0 \rightarrow \mathrm{ker}(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathrm{coker}(A)\rightarrow 0$.